# Why Strapi show deleted rows from database table (vacancies)? ( only on prod )

Tags: node.js, strapi

Why strapi show deleted row from db? How can i solve this? My localhost see only actual data from db, but production get some old or deleted row.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Is your localhost application connected to the same DB as the production one ?

Comment: yes it is same db but after. docker build i pull it to prod